# How to call Bootstrap alert with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Let's say I've the following piece of code:

```
<div class="alert alert-info fade in" id="bsalert">
  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
  <strong>Info!</strong> This alert box could indicate a neutral informative or action
</div>
```

How can I activate it manualy by using jQuery?

Comment: That particular Bootstrap component is just a HTML & CSS construct - there is no javascript involved. If you mean that you want to insert it in to the page dynamically, then you would need to write your own code to build the HTML and insert it in to the DOM where required, or have one in place in the page but make it hidden by default. You could then `hide()` or `show()` it as needed.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/ will help.

Comment: `$('#bsalert').fadeIn();`

Comment: Yeah, that's quite what I'm asking for. I do it because for BS's modals there is a special jQ method with which you can trigger a dialog box 'manualy', it's called `.modal();`. I couldn't find an analog of this for alerts and this brought me here. I think I've got it, thanks for the explanation. And while I'm writing this the exact answer came up, thanks @TonyHinkle. :)

Comment: What do you mean by activate?

Comment: I mean to trigger the alert, to make it show because I've to be able to do this in a function of mine... I've already sorted this problem out , thanks for the help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bootstrap uses the `in` and `out` class for visibility. You just need to toggle those classes. Also, if you want to keep the alert around once cancelled you can add a return false to the `close.bs.alert` event.

```js
function toggleAlert(){
    $(".alert").toggleClass('in out'); 
    return false; // Keep close.bs.alert event from removing from DOM
}


$("#btn").on("click", toggleAlert);
$('#bsalert').on('close.bs.alert', toggleAlert)
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Toggle</button>

<div class="alert alert-info fade out" id="bsalert">
  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
  <strong>Info!</strong> This alert box could indicate a neutral informative or action
</div>

<div>
    content
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the full answer you've given! I find it useful and halpful... definately one to use. :)